# Why does defining a variable of type of Smo.Server cause a 10 second delay

Tags: vb.net, smo

Bear with me here, ok!!

We use SMO a lot to do all kinds of things, including to check for the presence of particular stored procedures in the database.  So we have a method in our data access class called `HasProc`, which returns a boolean.  It's in a part of the application that hasn't been changed for over a year, possibly two years.

Lately, it's been taking ages (10s) to return a value, and I've been trying to pin down why.

It turns out that even defining the variable that will hold the SMO Server (***not instantiating it, just defining it***) causes a 10s delay in the code ***arriving into the function***.

Here's the relevant bit of the code, which just returns `True` now, for clarity:

```
Public Function HasProc(ByVal storedProcName As String) As Boolean
    Dim s As Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server
    Return True
End Function
```

In Visual Studio 12, stepping through the code using F11, the 10 second delay happens ***before the code highlight arrives*** at `Public Function etc..`.

If I comment out the `Dim` statement, it all runs instantly.

Even more weirdly, if I disable my ethernet adaptor, the delay does not occur.

This is reproducible across three computers.  I'm using VS2012, and SMO v11, to which we recently upgraded in order to support SQL Server 2012.

The other thing is that the delay happens even if the `Return True` statement is before, rather than after the `Dim` statement.

Any ideas?

Comment: Pause the debugger and look at the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

This would happen if the static initializer for that class performs network IO (which is generally a bad idea).

If you pause the debugger during the delay, you can find out exactly what it's doing.

Comment: Unfortunately, the only thing the debugger stops on is the line that calls the method containing the SMO call.  I created the object that calls the method in a separate line, so it should have been fully instantiated by the time it called HasProc.  I enabled the .NET Framework Source stepping option in Tools > Options > Debugging.

Comment: What happens if you pause again while it's frozen? What do you see in the Call Stack window?

Comment: Pausing while frozen gets nothing in the call stack between the line that calls the method, and the first line of the method once the delay has elapsed.